# Equivalent query for PDO as in Mysql

Tags: mysql, pdo

What is the equivalent of the following equivalent PDO?

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $num_articles){
$title=mysql_result( $sql_result_article,$i,"Article_Title");
$id =mysql_result( $sql_result_article,$i,"Article_Id");
$i++;
}
```

I tried it using:

```
$title = $select_spec_article_stmt->fetchColumn(0);
$nc=$select_spec_article_stmt->fetchColumn(1);
```

But I am still facing a problem as it is not showing proper records. When I comment the `$title` in PDO it shows proper records for `$nc`. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_result` always been ugliest way to handle mysql data. Please, do not take this approach into the brave new world of PDO.

Even with mysql ext you were able to use *an array*. So you have to use with PDO.
You don't need neither `mysql_result` nor `num_articles.`

Just get your data first:

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Now in a foreach loop you can either address each variable as an array member

```
<table>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="news.php?<?=$row['Article_Id']?>">
        <?=htmlspecialchars($row['Article_Title'])?>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
```

or, if you want to stick with scalar variables, use extract():

```
<table>
<? foreach ($data as $row): extract($row); ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="news.php?<?=$Article_Id?>">
        <?=htmlspecialchars($Article_Title)?>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
```

if you don't like these fancy bushy field names - don't use in the database